# List lines from another module in python pdb

Tags: python, pdb

Is any way to list lines from another module in pdb?

For example, if I want to set a breakpoint in the current file, I can use the 'l' command to find the line number, and set a breakpoint on that line.

But if I want to set a breakpoint in another file, there is syntax to give the filename in the 'b' command, but how can I list the other file in order to find the line I want to break on?

Nothing analogous to 
list FILE:LINENUM
in gdb?

Comment: If you add "import pdb; pdb.set_trace()" to every place you want a breakpoint in your code, pdb will stop there (though it won't list it as a breakpoint).

Comment: You could create/extend Pdb to handle it:  http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/eb0921b2100b/Lib/pdb.py#l782 Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there are any convenient hook methods to use to make the magic happen, so in your subclass, you'll probably end up copying all that code and making minor tweaks here and there...